# List Top Daily Rentals Per Customer using a CTE

Tags: mysql, query, select, cte

I've been trying to learn CTEs and having a bit or trouble getting the hang of them.  I wrote a query against the [Sakila Sample database](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/sakila/en/) that lists information about horror movie rentals for each day.

Here is the overblown (and redundant) SQL that I came up with:

```
SELECT CONCAT(CU.last_name, ', ', CU.first_name) AS customer,
        A.phone, 
        F.title, 
        date(R.rental_date) AS rental_date
 FROM sakila.rental R 
     LEFT JOIN sakila.inventory I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id 
     LEFT JOIN sakila.film F ON I.film_id = F.film_id 
     LEFT JOIN sakila.film_category FC on F.film_id = FC.film_id
     LEFT JOIN sakila.category C ON FC.category_id = C.category_id 
     LEFT JOIN sakila.customer CU ON R.customer_id = CU.customer_id
     LEFT JOIN sakila.address A ON CU.address_id = A.address_id
 WHERE CU.customer_id in 
       (SELECT CU.customer_id
        FROM rental R
        LEFT JOIN sakila.customer CU ON R.customer_id = CU.customer_id
        LEFT JOIN sakila.inventory I ON R.inventory_id = I.inventory_id 
        LEFT JOIN sakila.film F ON I.film_id = F.film_id 
        LEFT JOIN sakila.film_category FC on F.film_id = FC.film_id
        LEFT JOIN sakila.category C ON FC.category_id = C.category_id 
        WHERE C.name = "Horror"
        GROUP BY CU.customer_id
        HAVING COUNT(CU.customer_id) >= 3)
 AND C.name = "Horror"
 ORDER BY customer, title, rental_date DESC;
```

And here are some of the results in my database client ([Navicat for MySQL](https://www.navicat.com/en/products/navicat-for-mysql)):

[image: Daily Horror Movie Rentals Query in Navicat for MySQL]

**Is there a way to rewrite the query using a CTE?**

It seems like just the type of query that a CTE would be perfect for, if only I could figure it out!

Thanks!

Comment: what do you expect the output to look like?

Comment: Move whole subquery into CTE query. Convert WHERE IN to WHERE EXISTS. And replace some LEFT JOINs to INNER (look at your WHERE conditions) both in CTE and main query.

Comment: I would like the same output, just shorter SQL.

Answer (score 0):

```
# horror film rental(answer)
select cus_dtl.name, cus_dtl.phone, hf_cus.title, hf_cus.rental_date, hf_cus.name
from (select c.customer_id, concat(c.first_name, ',', c.last_name) as name, a.phone
      from customer as c, address as a
      where c.address_id = a.address_id) as cus_dtl, (select r.customer_id, r.rental_date, hf_inve.title, hf_inve.name
                                                      from rental as r, (select i.inventory_id, hf_title.film_id, hf_title.title, hf_title.name
                                                                         from inventory as i, (select f.title, horror_FID.film_id, horror_FID.name
                                                                                               from film as f, (select fc.film_id, horror.name
                                                                                                                from film_category as fc, (select category_id, name
                                                                                                                                           from category
                                                                                                                                           where name = 'horror') as horror
                                                                                                                where fc.category_id = horror.category_id) as horror_FID
                                                                                               where f.film_id = horror_FID.film_id) as hf_title
                                                                         where i.film_id = hf_title.film_id) as hf_inve
                                                      where r.inventory_id = hf_inve.inventory_id) as hf_cus
where hf_cus.customer_id = cus_dtl.customer_id
order by cus_dtl.name, hf_cus.title, hf_cus.rental_date desc;
```

using sub queries..

[image]

Comment: Not sure that that's an improvement.  Maybe my query was about right?